# Should deleted answers prevent a question from being Roomba'ed?

Tags: support, bug, deleted-answers, auto-delete

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1448065/4751173) should qualify as an [abandoned question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) eligible to be Roomba'ed: it seems to satisfy all criteria. (It has quite some views, but certainly less than the threshold, because it's already 12 years old.) I suspect it is not because of the [deleted answer (Wayback Machine snapshot)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151102033631/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448065/ssl-problem-client-side-caching-js-css), but that feels like a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) to me.

Comment: [Screenshot with the deleted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkpd5.png) for full context.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the screenshot, the answer was automatically deleted as a negatively-scored post when its author's account was deleted. It's possible that the check is looking at a cached count of answers, which is not updated when an answer is automatically deleted on user deletion or destroyal. A similar thing happens for comment counts: the cached count used to indicate how many more comments are to be shown is not updated when comments are removed due to their author being destroyed.

Comment: I was about to wipe some SEDE, but it seems that you already did. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1537509/roomba-removeabandonedquestions-based-on-deleted-answers-as-well It's a bug, because from the purpose of of the logic having a deleted answer and "no answers" is the same.

Comment: IME, deleted answers don't prevent the Roomba. However, in investigations/testing for Roomba Forecaster, there have periodically been questions which qualify under all published criteria, but which don't get deleted (enough such that I explicitly handle that case). It's remained unclear what criteria prevent those deletions. However, the questions *usually* end up deleted by the Roomba shortly after I encounter them, even if they qualified for deletion for years, but were not deleted in that time. This implies either caching of some sort or something associated with just viewing the question.

Comment: As is consistent with my prior experience, [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1448065/3773011) was deleted by the Roomba when it did the `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` task a few hours ago.

Comment: @Makyen ah, right. Then perhaps it's not entirely deterministic, just like the badge award scripts?

Comment: I've posted a question about that behavior (cc @Makyen): [Do the automated deletion scripts not run on questions that aren't viewed that often?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375250/do-the-automated-deletion-scripts-not-run-on-questions-that-arent-viewed-that-o)